# How to check User input type(Data type) in scala?

Tags: scala, bigdata

I want to check the user input type(Data type) from console in scala? I need to check whether the input data is Int,String,Double, Float.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the type, I would use the input directly. Try:

```
val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine() 

if (Try(input.toInt).isSuccess) ...  // It is an integer
else if (Try(input.toFloat).isSuccess) ... // It is a float
else if (Try(input.toDouble).isSuccess) ... // It is a double
else ... // No need to convert to string
```

Comment: It should be val input instead of val intput

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scala`'s strongest api `match` `case` for this case as

```
scala>     def findDataType(x: Any) = x match {
     |       case x : String => println("String identified")
     |       case x : Int => println("Integer identified")
     |       case x : Float => println("Float identified")
     |       case x : Double => println("Double identified")
     |       case _ => println("DataType not identified")
     |     }
findDataType: (x: Any)Unit

scala> findDataType("abcd")
String identified

scala> findDataType(1)
Integer identified

scala> findDataType(1.0)
Double identified

scala> findDataType(1D)
Double identified

scala> findDataType(1f)
Float identified

scala> findDataType('c')
DataType not identified
```

We can read in from console and pass to the above function as

```
scala> findDataType(scala.io.StdIn.readInt())
Integer identified

scala> findDataType(scala.io.StdIn.readLine())
String identified

scala> findDataType(scala.io.StdIn.readFloat())
Float identified
```

**Edited**

You can use regex patterns as below(I have used only integer and float)

```
scala> val INT_PATTERN: String = "^[-+]?[0-9]*$"
INT_PATTERN: String = ^[-+]?[0-9]*$

scala>   val FLOAT_PATTERN: String = "^[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$"
FLOAT_PATTERN: String = ^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

And define the function as

```
scala> def findDataType(value: Any) = {
     | if(value.toString.matches(INT_PATTERN)) println("Integer identified")
     | else if(value.toString.matches(FLOAT_PATTERN)) println("Float identified")
     | else println("String identified")
     | }
findDataType: (value: Any)Unit
```

Calling the function with `scala.io.StdIn.readLine()` as below would give the exact datatype

```
scala> findDataType(scala.io.StdIn.readLine()) // 2 is entered
Integer identified

scala> findDataType(scala.io.StdIn.readLine()) //ab is entered
String identified

scala> findDataType(scala.io.StdIn.readLine()) // 2.1 is entered
Float identified
```

This can be done for other datatype as well.

Comment: That wouldn't work as the type of the val read from console is already a String. The question asked for determining the datatype from the string read from console.

Comment: @VivekKothari Not everything that you read from Console is String, it depends how you read it. for example if you read like scala.io.StdIn.readLine() then its a string but if you read like val intput  = scala.io.StdIn.readInt() then its an integer. I hope you got me. Then you can pass the val to the function above to get the datatype. :)

Comment: Agreed. The question is not descriptive enough to illustrate how is the data being read. If @sumit were invoking the readInt, readFloat method, why would you even want to determine the type? Its already of the desired type :)

Comment: @VivekKothari Thats the reason I answered it like above. :) I am glad that you understood.

Comment: I am also working on same problem. As of now, the solution hints towards turning to Regex and catching Exceptions. Will update, once done.